# Is there any WhatsApp Message API for ASP.NET MVC 4.5 ? I need to send messages in bulk(list of numbers)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

Is there any WhatsApp Message API for ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.5 ? I need to send messages in bulk (list of numbers). Please help, I need to integrate it into my ASP.NET MVC application.

I'm currently using a SMS service provider, I want to switch from sim SMS to Whatsapp SMS. So I need help with that please.

Comment: Integrating WhatsApp API into your ASP.NET MVC application will involve making HTTP requests to the API provider endpoints. Which provider you choose is up to you. It can be an official solution (more expensive) or an unofficial solution (more risks).